# Excel function to copy cell value above IF current cell empty and another cell in same row is anything but empty. Otherwise, do nothing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel function to copy cell value above IF current cell is empty and another cell in same row is anything but empty. Otherwise, do nothing, and leave current cell value in place (empty or not.) 
This is what I currently have `=IF(AND(F48="",AJ61<>""),E47,E48)`. This works for a single specific line of data, but, then messes up when copied down the remainder of the column.

Example of what I need:

```
      A         B        C
1] Apple___    Yes

2] ________    Yes

3] ________

4] Orange__    Yes
```

I need to Copy `A1` (Apple) into `A2` IF `A2` is Empty and `B2` is anything except empty. While not Copying `A2` into `A3` since that row is empty.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want with formulas, you'll probably need to use VBA.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad You'd be surprised what people like ScottC can do with a formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enter/copy/fill a formula into a cell without overwriting the data that is already there. You need to enter the formula into just the blank cells. You can do this by:

Starting from the first cell where you want the formula, select to the last cell you want to contain the formula, including all the cells in between.

Then press Ctrl-G to open the Go to menu.

Click 'Special'

Select 'Blanks'

Click 'OK'

Put this formula into the formula bar:
`=IF(COUNTA(B2:F2),A1,"")`

Then press `CTRL`+`ENTER` to fill the formula into all selected cells.

This formula checks that B2:F2 is blank... change that range to match how much of the row you need to check as being blank.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the details and apology for the delay. Actually, I want this code to auto run when a new row is created. The above solution i think will work fine with the existing rows. But is it possible to run the code automatically when a new row is inserted. An automate flow creates a row so I want the empty cells in the new row auto filled with a specific cell value. Thanks

Comment: That's too different to the above scenario, you'll need to ask a new question and provide examples of your data and your desired outcome. Also provide clarification on the automate flow that is creating the new row.